# Does anyone know what the white spots (see picture below) in mint leaves are?

Tags: mint

The mint plants grown in pots has some white mold type deposits on the leaf. See picture below. Does anyone know what it is?

[image: mint leaves with some white spots]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks just like powdery mildew that we had on our spearmint. I would pronounce it powdery mildew. You could treat it. I hear [milk](http://www.growingformarket.com/articles/powdery-mildew-solutions) works great for the purpose. There are probably a lot of sites that explain how to treat it. Another solution might be better with mint, though.

Comment: I tried spraying milk and the plants are in better shape now. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that a milk spray (we use 1 part milk 1 part water) does great at treating powdery mildew and downy mildew. But you have to spray it every day, and for another 7 days after PM is gone. I only used cow's milk.